# Is there an easy way to pin a DataTip in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, datatip

Sometimes pinning a DataTip in Visual Studio 2010 is not very easy using the mouse, e.g:

[image]

If the DataTip is very long (as shown above), it can be quite tricky to move the mouse cursor from the variable to the "pin" icon. Sometimes the DataTip will disappear as soon as the mouse is moved outside of the DataTip area.

Is there an easy way to pin DataTips, e.g. a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(In addition to Werolik's answer)

It seems, that by default no keyboard shortcut is defined to pin a DataTip. But it is possible to define a custom shortcut:

- go to *Tools* --> *Customize...* --> *Keyboard...*
- search for commands containing *PinToSource*
- set a custom shortcut key combination

Answer (score 4):

You can use the context menu. Just click on the variable to pin and than choose "Pin to source".

[image]